# Proper way to create plot of equation with parameter solutions

Tags: plotting, equation-solving, numerics

for example I am trying to execute this code:

```
f[x_, a_] := Sin[x] - a
g[a_] := NSolve[f[x, a] == 0 && x > 0 && x < 6]
Plot[x /. g[a], {a, -1, 1}]
```

Then I'm receiving plot with "holes" like this one:[image]

How can I avoid this effect? After all I insist to use NSolve function, so any "parametric" solutions don't satisfy me.

Comment: will PlotPoints solve your problem? also, in this occasion, I advise you yo use FindRoot instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the first argument in `Plot` must have a constant form. In your example sometimes 2 solutions are found and sometimes 1 solution only. Hence the form varies between `{_,_}` and `{_}`. With the following modification, the form `{_,_}` occurs Lebesgue almost surely, which suffices:

```
f[x_, a_] := Sin[x] - a
g[a_] := NSolve[f[x, a] == 0 && x > 0 && x < 2 \[Pi]]
Plot[x /. g[a], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

However, as soon as `f` is defined differently, this may no longer be the case, so different code should be used.

Also, the plot dependents on the order of the solutions from `NSolve` in an unfortunate fashion:

```
f[x_, a_] := Sin[x] - a
g[a_] := RandomSample[NSolve[f[x, a] == 0 && x > 0 && x < 2 \[Pi]]]
Plot[x /. g[a], {a, -1, 1}]
```

[image]

For the function in the question you could do:

```
ParametricPlot[{Sin[x], x}, {x, 0, 6}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

Which also works for other functions if they exhibit a left inverse. Is that the case for all functions in your context?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Your explanations were really helpful.

Comment: Recommend that you add the option `Exclusions -> 0` to the `Plot`